# Architectural Design -Building a real time free text search functionality in an application?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, bigdata

I am working on an application which is basically event management kind of application. Where user can post different types of events. Events can be short noticed events like a user throwing a birthday party in next 2 hours or pre planned events like marathon etc (This is just a dummy example).
Now the requirement is this that other user when search through free text search they will able to get both kind of results . The search will be more like linkedIn search , other than event there are other categories also.

I was thinking of using ElasticSearch or Solr. but both of them are lucene based search engine. When I will be writing a lot of data in real time to these search engines , the data will be written to cache and then periodically flush out to disk in different segments.
To optimize the search performance lucene based engine try to co-locate the data using segmentation process. In frequent write case these process become frequent and lot of resources will be consumed by this and the search performance will be degraded finally.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html

Is there any way by which I could achive real time free text search without costing much of performance in segmentation. Please suggest any architectural design which will best suit in this scenario

Comment: Have you actually tried using ES or Solr? I'm fairly certain you'll be able to handle most traffic thrown at it in the beginning, and if needed, after tuning it to fit your requirements when you actually see where you might have performance issues.

Comment: @MatsLindh The write operation is already very high and the data I need to aggregate from three different collection in mongodb to fed into ES or Solr. As well change in any document in any collection which is very frequent and hence I think because of above reason ES or Solr is not suitable. I was wondering how facebook or linkedIn uses it search engine.